# Python division failing?

Tags: python, division

I must be missing something.

```
f = open(e, "r")
total = os.path.getsize(e)
for line in f:
   progress = f.tell()/total
   print progress
```

This is printing 0.
Outputing total and f.tell() show me they are valid and type() tells me they are long. So there must be something about diving a long that I have missed/forgotten. What am I missing?

Comment: @wim only if neither of the operands is floating-point.

Comment: @wim / is division. // is floor division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making one of the values a `float` to prevent your quotient from being rounded down to `0`:

```
progress = float(f.tell()) / total
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2.x, dividing an integer by an integer results in an integer. Make one a float first.

Comment: Learn something new everyday. Thanks.